# Server updates does not reflect the client browser?

Tags: javascript, express, server, client, endpoint

Why server updates doesn't reflect on client browser, Maybe an attribute value should be changed ?, something related to caching ?

```
app.get('/hello' , (_ , res) => {
    res.header({
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    });
    res.json('HelloWorld');
});
```

that should help but it didn't !

Comment: Did you try to wrap your response in an object ? Like res.json({res: 'HelloWorld'})

Comment: That didn't solve the thing, made some searches, it is related to Websockets (idk exactly what is that), turns out it is a bit complicated, anyways thanks for your contribution Hedi

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, HTTP and HTTPS are a request and response protocol. You will only receive data from the server when you ask for it.

If you want real-time changes from server to client, you can use WebSockets. They basically establish a connection between the client and the browser and events are triggered where you can share messages.

Here is the API Documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

A slightly easier explanation:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-web-socket-and-how-it-is-different-from-the-http/

Answer (score 0):

**Note: in development mode: each time you change/update some line of the code you need to save the code and restart the server in order for changes to take effect on client**

**if your are new to nodejs(express) "nodmon package" can help you which development to reflecting the changes in client side from the serve side without need to restart the server each time you update some code.you only need to save the code.

you can check details aboutt nodemon [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon).

or follow the steps given below:-

**Step1:** install nodemon by running the code below on terminal

```
 npm i nodemon
```

**Step2: ** start the server with

```
nodemon <server file name>
eg.
nodemon index.js
```

now the changes you make on serve would be reflected to client without need to restart the server